# Add optional argument to the caption to get into figure list entry

Tags: macros, captions

I would like to add the optional list entry, which is used for a `listoffigures`, also to the caption.

In this basic example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{baz}
\caption[Baz]{Foo Bar}
\end{figure}

\input{foo}
\end{document}
```

the caption should read "**Figure 1:** Baz- Foo Bar" instead of the default "**Figure 1:** Foo Bar". Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add the optional argument, you can patch `\@caption` which passes its contents on to `\@makecaption`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{#3}{#2~--~#3}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This just inserts the second argument of `\@caption` (containing the optional argument to `\caption` as part of the main caption:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\usepackage{caption,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{caption,graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{#3}{#2~--~#3}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering\includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption[Baz]{Foo Bar}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note the requirement to use a `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair. For more on this see [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764).

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to do this globally, you can just use

```
\caption[Baz]{Baz~--~Foo Bar}
```

which would be a local (verbatim) version of the above.

---

For this to work successfully with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), a larger-scale replacement of contents within `\@caption` is required, as offered by [`regexpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch)'s `\xpatchcmd*` replace-all patch:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\usepackage{caption,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{caption,graphicx}
\usepackage{regexpatch,hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{regexpatch,hyperref}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\@caption}{#3}{#2~--~#3}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering\includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption[Baz]{Foo Bar}\label{myfig}
\end{figure}

See Figure~\ref{myfig} with title~\nameref{myfig}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answers the question perfectly, but is there also a way to use it with the nameref and/or the hyperref package?

Comment: @panther: I've updated my answer to include support for [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref).

Comment: Works like charm, thanks. For other people it should be notified, that the regexpatch is not part of TeXLive 2009. IMHO at least TeXLive 2012 is required. In my personal experience, the installation of TexLive2013, to a extra directory with the install script from http://www.tug.org/texlive/, was less hassle than using a package based update. Many TeX editors can be configured which version to use.

Comment: this doesn't work for me :(. There is no error, just that the short option is not shown. Could it be because I'm also using the `subcaption` package ? But I load it before patching

Comment: actually, for the second version, `\usepackage{regexpatch}` throws an error saying that `l3regex is obsolete`